# Trying to get property 'latitude' of non-object i'm trying to get the latitude and longitude from the users in an app i'm creating and i get this

Tags: php, laravel

So I tried to use a popular function to get the latitude and longitude of the users but when I run it I get the error above. this is the code in  different parts of my laravel project for this function:

controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Stevebauman\Location\Facades\Location;

class HealthController extends Controller
{
     public function showHealth(Request $request)
        {
        $ip = $request->ip();
        $data = Location::get($ip);

        return view ('healthcode',compact('data'));
        }
}

views:

<html>
<head>
    <title>How to get current user location in laravel</title>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center;">
    <h1> How to get current user location in laravel - websolutionstuff.com</h1>
    <div style="border:1px solid black; margin-left: 300px; margin-right: 300px;">
    <h3>Latitude: {{ $data->latitude }}</h3>
    <h3>Longitude: {{ $data->longitude }}</h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please `dd(Location::get($ip))` in your controller, and check if shows latitude and longitude.

Comment: Please check https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-get-visitors-ip-location-and-city

Comment: What debugging did you try? Eg did you check `$ip` is really set as expected?

Comment: Replace `$ip = $request->ip();` with: `$ip = $request->ip;` or `$ip = $request->input('ip');`

Comment: @AkhzarJaved when i do that i get this error (syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN))

Comment: @Militaru it works but for some reason i'm getting so coordinates from united states while i'm in china